# How to recursively walk through directories and subdirectories and create CSV summary file on what has been received into a folder

Tags: pandas, pathlib

I will be receiving files into a directory and the information will be stored in nested subdirectories like below. With the actual files that represent images (DICOM File format) at the deepest sub directory.

Organised:

```
Structure:
|- Year
  |- Month
    |- Day
      |- Study/Examination
        |- Modality
          |- Images

Example Structure
|- 2023/
   |- 2/
     |- 6/
       |- 2/
         |- nif11/
           |- file1.dcm
           |- file2.dcm
       |- 3/
           |- nif12/
             |- file1.dcm
     |- 7/
       |- 1/
         |- nif15/
           |- file1.dcm
           |- file2.dcm
           |- file3.dcm
   |- 3/
     |- 6/
       |- 2/
         |- nif10/
           |- file1.dcm
           |- file2.dcm
```

The objective is to crawl through the directories and and create a record in a CSV file that represents a study/examination for a participant. This folder level represents a test performed with multiple modalities involved within (nif). This folder representing a study /examination is 4 levels deep so don't know whether we could use this standard structure to achieve this.

The way files are being dropped in this folder and its subdirectories is not ideal, dumped as per date as opposed to institution so I will need to be able to access the .dcm files (deepest sub directory) and extract metadata that is stored in here.

I will be using a library `pydicom` to achieve this but I wanted to get advice on how to best extract the study level so when I extract the associated metadata I can tag these data elements on as extra columns (Participant name, Institution, modality, etc.) to this record i have created form the folder structure.

I have used `Pathlib` before in the past to do filesystem related work but this is trickier for me.

Comment: Are you asking about accessing specific parts of a path object? e.g. `Path("2023/3/6/2/nif10/file2.dcm").parts` - so you'd want `2` and `nif10` here?

Answer (score 0):

I think `glob` is what you are after, and the fact that you can just get the info from the `split`ted file path. I've created two files (test.txt) in the structure that you depicted. Change `.txt` for your extension of files:

```
files = glob('./example/**/*.txt', recursive=True)

for file in files:
    print("File path: ", file)
    print("Study: ", file.split("/")[5])
```

result (with my minimal setup);

```
File path:  ./example/2023/02/14/study2/file1.txt
Study:  study2
File path:  ./example/2023/02/14/study1/file1.txt
Study:  study1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you wanted to generate a csv file containing the list of all the files and having the folders as columns in the csv.
This is what the code below will do.

CODE:

```
# STRUCTURE:
# |- Year
#   |- Month
#     |- Day
#       |- Study/Examination
#         |- Modality
#           |- Images


import glob


def createCSV(PARENTFOLDER,OUTFILE,SEPARATOR):
    LEVELS=PARENTFOLDER.split(SEPARATOR)
    STRUCTURE=PARENTFOLDER+SEPARATOR+'*'+SEPARATOR+'*'+SEPARATOR+'*'+SEPARATOR+'*'+SEPARATOR+'*'+SEPARATOR+'*.dcm' #this is the folder structure under the main folder
    f = open(OUTFILE,'w')
    filelist = glob.glob(STRUCTURE, recursive=True)
    for eachfile in filelist:
        data=eachfile
        eachfile=eachfile.replace(PARENTFOLDER+SEPARATOR, "")
        EACHFILEPARTS=eachfile.split(SEPARATOR)
        for eachlevel in EACHFILEPARTS:
            data=data+','+eachlevel
        f.write(data)
        f.write('\n')
    f.close()

createCSV('/tmp/structure','/tmp/structure.csv','/')
```

RESULTING FILE IS /tmp/structure.csv:

```
/tmp/structure/2023/02/14/STUDY1/MODALITY1/FILE1.DCM,2023,02,14,STUDY1,MODALITY1,FILE1.DCM
```